# Override Eloquent model where() method

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, eloquent

I'm trying to cache my models to avoid repeated database lookups. I was able to easily override the `find` method as follows:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Concerns;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

trait CachesModels
{

    protected function findInCache(...$args)
    {
        $id = $args[0];
        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $key = self::class . "|" . $id;
            $timeout = config("app.cache_seconds");
            return Cache::remember($key, $timeout, function() use ($args) {
                return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), "find", $args);
            });
        }
        return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), "find", $args);
    }

    public static function find(...$args)
    {
        return (new static)->findInCache($args);
    }
}
```

By using this trait on my models, I'm able to cache the results of the `find()` method. However, this doesn't account for the other related methods (e.g. `findOrFail`) and, more importantly, doesn't use the cache for dependency injection on my controller methods.

After going through the middleware and tracing code, it looks like I can use the cache in all these cases by overriding the `where()` method. As with `find()`, this isn't a defined method on the parent class, and can also be called statically or on an instance. So I tried the following code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Concerns;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

trait CachesModels
{
    protected function whereInCache($parameters)
    {
        // only cache simple calls, e.g. where('id', 123)
        if (count($parameters) === 2 && is_numeric($parameters[1]) && $parameters[0] === $this->getKeyName()) {
            $key = self::class . "|" . $parameters[1];
            $timeout = config("app.cache_seconds");
            return Cache::remember($key, $timeout, function() use ($parameters) {
                return parent::where(...$parameters);
            });
        }
        return parent::where(...$parameters);
    }

    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if ($method === "where") {
            return $this->whereInCache($parameters);
        }
        return parent::__call($method, $parameters);
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
    {
        if ($method === "where") {
            return (new static)->whereInCache($parameters);
        }
        return parent::__callStatic($method, $parameters);
    }
}
```

However, when I try running this code, I get a recursion error:

```
PHP Error:  Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
    in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1161
```

---

I've also tried replacing `return parent::where(...$parameters);` with `return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), "where", $parameters);` as used in the `Model::__call()` method, but that gives me a different error:

```
Exception with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed'
```

On the cache closure return line. Not sure about this error since the method should return an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up being able to replicate the recursion error with this simple code:

```php
<?php

class A {
    public static function foo() {
        echo "3";
    }
}

class B {
    public function __call($m, $p) {
        echo "2";
        A::foo();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public function foo() {
        echo "1";
        parent::foo();
    }
    public function __call($m, $p){
        echo "x";
        $this->foo();
    }
}

(new C)->foo();
// output: 1x1x1x1x1x1x...
```

This output is unexpected – it appears calling an unreachable method on `B` is triggering `C::__call()` instead of `B::__call()`. Replacing the call to `parent::foo()` with `parent::__call("foo", null)` resolves this error, and gives the expected output of `123`. An excellent reminder why "magic" methods are a nightmare.

---

Having resolved that, I'm back to `Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed`. As mentioned in the question, the function should return an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, however this object does contain a closure and there's no way around that problem.

My solution is to override `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveRouteBinding()`, as well as the `find` and `findOrFail` methods. It's still not ideal, but covers most cases where I'm hitting the database repeatedly. A simple event listener refreshes the cache entry if the model is updated:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Concerns;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

trait CachesModels
{
    public static function bootCachesModels()
    {
        static::updated(function($model) {
            $key = $model->getCacheKey();
            $timeout = $model->getCacheTimeout();
            Cache::forget($key);
            Cache::put($key, $model, $timeout);
        });
        static::deleted(function($model) {
            $key = $model->getCacheKey();
            Cache::forget($key);
        });
    }

    private function getCacheKey(int $id = null)
    {
        return self::class . "|" . ($id ?? $this->getKey());
    }

    private function getCacheTimeout()
    {
        return config("app.cache_seconds");
    }

    private function findInCache($args)
    {
        $id = $args[0];
        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $key = $this->getCacheKey($id);
            $timeout = $this->getCacheTimeout();
            return Cache::remember($key, $timeout, function() use ($args) {
                return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), "find", $args);
            });
        }
        return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), "find", $args);
    }

    private function findOrFailInCache($args)
    {
        $id = $args[0];
        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $key = $this->getCacheKey($id);
            $timeout = $this->getCacheTimeout();
            return Cache::remember($key, $timeout, function() use ($args) {
                return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), "findOrFail", $args);
            });
        }
        return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), "findOrFail", $args);
    }

    public static function find(...$args)
    {
        return (new static)->findInCache($args);
    }

    public static function findOrFail(...$args)
    {
        return (new static)->findOrFailInCache($args);
    }

    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
    {
        // only cache when route binding is based on primary key
        if ($field !== null && $field !== $this->getKeyName()) {
            return parent::resolveRouteBinding($value, $field);
        }
        $key = $this->getCacheKey($value);
        $timeout = $this->getCacheTimeout();
        return Cache::remember($key, $timeout, function() use($value, $field) {
            return parent::resolveRouteBinding($value, $field);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is an infinite recursion (something calling itself over and over again, until it bugs out after 256 levels of recursion); and the second one is based upon, that anonymous functions (aka [Closure](https://www.php.net/closure)) cannot be serialized (at least not by default, in order to prevent code injection).

It may well be that the Laravel framework is calling a method, not necessarily your code.
eg. when listening for `Model` on-update and than trying to save the `Model` in there. In such situations, one has to use `DB` instead of `Model`, in order not to create an infinite recursion.